# Fill horizontal space with adjacent notebooks in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to tkinter and I've having trouble getting notebooks to fill horizontal space. I would like to place two notebooks at the top of the window, side-by-side. Each notebook should occupy half of the horizontal space of the window.

I initially tried using `pack`, but that made the notebooks expand unevenly, the right notebook took up more space than the left notebook. I thought that `grid` would work better, but I can't figure out how to get them to expand, even with passing `weight=1` to `columnconfigure`.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("800x100")

status = tk.Frame(root)

left_tabs = ttk.Notebook(status)
tab_a = tk.Frame(left_tabs)
tab_b = tk.Frame(left_tabs)
left_tabs.add(tab_a, text="a")
left_tabs.add(tab_b, text="b")
# left_tabs.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.X, expand=True)
left_tabs.grid(row=0, column=0)

right_tabs = ttk.Notebook(status)
tab_c = tk.Frame(right_tabs)
tab_d = tk.Frame(right_tabs)
tab_e = tk.Frame(right_tabs)
right_tabs.add(tab_c, text="c")
right_tabs.add(tab_d, text="d")
right_tabs.add(tab_e, text="e")
# right_tabs.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.X, expand=True)
right_tabs.grid(row=0, column=1)

tk.Label(tab_a, text="testing").pack()
tk.Label(tab_c, text="testing").pack()

status.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
status.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
status.pack(fill=tk.X)

title = tk.Label(root, text="title", bg="grey")
title.pack(fill=tk.X)

tk.mainloop()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grid` allows you to request that two or more rows or columns have a uniform width or height. This option name is `uniform` - if two or more columns have the same setting for `uniform`, they will always be the same width. The value of `uniform` doesn't matter, as long as it is the same.

```
status.columnconfigure(0, weight=1, uniform="x")
status.columnconfigure(1, weight=1, uniform="x")
```

[image: screenshot after setting uniform option]

In addition, you need to use the `sticky` option so that your notebooks fill the space that has been allocated to them.

```
left_tabs.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
right_tabs.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")
```

[image: screenshot after adding sticky option]

Answer (score 1):

To make a **gridded layout have all columns have the same width**, you've got to configure those columns to have the same weight and to be in the same `uniform group`. This configuration is associated with the master widget, not any of the contained widgets (because columns can contain many widgets, of course).

> **sticky**
>
> Defines how to expand the widget if the resulting cell is larger than
>   the widget itself. This can be any combination of the constants S, N,
>   E, and W, or NW, NE, SW, and SE.
>
> For example, W (west) means that the widget should be aligned to the
>   left cell border. W+E means that the widget should be stretched
>   horizontally to fill the whole cell. W+E+N+S means that the widget
>   should be expanded in both directions. Default is to center the widget
>   in the cell.

specifying the `sticky` argument when you do grid:

```
left_tabs.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="NESW")
status.columnconfigure(0, weight=1, uniform="group_name")


right_tabs.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="NESW")
status.columnconfigure(1, weight=1, uniform="group_name")
```

Comment: That seems a bit better, but it still has the uneven problem I mentioned with `pack` ([screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/BNmGg48.png)). Is there a way to ensure that both notebooks fill to the same width? I know I can set a specific width with specific values, but I'd prefer the layout to be scalable.

Comment: I just added a screenshot to my first comment, you can see that the right notebook is wider. Seems like the text in the tab titles is making it wider than it should be.

Comment: In your case width is adapted to number of your tabs, if you add more tabs it will be wider, did you try with sticky argument?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using the sticky arguments. You can see the full code that made that screenshot [here](https://hasteb.in/ahiqihav.py).